# Folders within Visual Studio Projects

Tags: visual-studio, directory

Can I have a freehand in using any arbitrary folder hierarchy within a Visual Studio project? Does the runtime/VS actually care about how I create the folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't care about the folder structure you use. Everything is typically tied together based on file types and the references in your project (csproj, vbproj, etc) file.

That said: in general it is best to stick to the conventions laid out by Microsoft for common files, since people are used to look for them in the places.